# The data can not to be updated on AG-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I just used [AG-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/) in our React project and I just changed the data structure of rowData like below:

```js
const data =  [
    { 
        tail: '1M', 
        live_1Y1Y: { 
            value: 3.0, 
            target: 'live_1Y1Y_1M' 
         }
    }
];
```

and my colDefs is:

```js
[
    { 
        headerName: 'TAIL', 
        field: 'tail', 
        width: 100 
    },
    { 
        headerName: '1Y1Y', 
        field: 'live_1Y1Y',
        valueGetter: function (params) { 
            return params.data[params.colDef.field]['value']; 
        }
    }
]
```

When the **value: 3.0** is changed, I can't see any update on the page. I also set the

```js
deltaRowDataMode={true}
getRowNodeId={data => data.id}
```

but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful link in the documentation about change detection:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-change-detection/.

Here's a helpful link in the documentation about view refresh:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/.

A couple of other things to consider:

1. If you have valueCache set to true, it caches the value of your valueGetter
2. Did you intend to declare data with const?  If it's going to change later, it may be better to use let instead of const.